# SignalR using websockets keeps the same User Identity when login/logout during active connection

Tags: signalr

I am running ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application on server2012 using SignalR with settings enabling websockets.

On the page there is Log In / Log Out button, and I have to maintain active connections on server.

When server used for transport serverSentEvents everything works fine and when user changed authentication I got callback to

```
$.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
    // stop current signalR connection and start new one        
    createNewConnection();
});
```

but when I set up server for websockets, it stopped to call error function. I found in fora that common solution would be to ping server periodically and update cookies, but when I ping server using signalR - websockets, server does not recognize that user identity has changed.

Basically when I start connection with user logged already in and then click on log out, server will maintain websocket connection unchanged, with the same user identity:

```
Context.User.Identity.Name
```

will be the same after user logged out.

I know that user identity cannot change during active signalR connection, but I would need to check if cookies didn't change, as it can change from another opened tab or window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're seeing is 100% expected.  With all transports EXCEPT WebSockets they all have intermittent communication.

Ex: SSE - There's 1 connection that's established and never broken to receive information and there's AJAX requests that are triggered whenever you attempt to send data from the client to the server, the AJAX requests being the intermittent requests.

Now, on each request to the server SignalR validates the user identity.  Sooo for every client -> server send in SSE the user identity is validated. However, in WebSockets there's only ever 1 request active (to instantiate the connection) and sends and receives flow bidirectionally over the connection.

Therefore, since WebSockets only ever has 1 request it never knows about identity changes.

On the other hand, if you are using SignalR 2.0.0+ your connection will learn of an invalid user identity within a 5 minute time span (SignalR sends an ajax request every 5 mins to the server).

Hope this information helps!

Comment: Thanks Taylor, I thing best way how to check if user identity has changed is to ping server with ajax request.